# Predictive inference of interval sampling for proportions?

Tags: prediction

Suppose I am sampling periodically (each month) over a year a substance that is degrading over time. The process of sampling is destructive so I am using difference samples each month. At the end of the year less that 95% of my total samples should have been categorized as "good" in order to make my experiment successful.

Example: N = 120 samples total over a year and I am using 10 of those each month.

My question is: What should be the best way to calculated after each monthly sampling if I still statistically on target under a certain confidence interval?

Thank you